# How do I cover the Bootstrap modal backdrop on the whole screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

#### Scenario

I tried to cover backdrop on the whole screen but when I open my modal backdrop, the start from the header stays out of my modal backdrop. How can I cover the backdrop on the whole screen?

> Modal HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDetailFormalite" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="contact">Détails</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" onclick="hideModalDetailFormalite()">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row" id="detailsFlows">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-common" id="btnAddToCardDocFlows" disabled="disabled">
                    <i class='fa fa fa-cart-plus' id="iconBtnAddToCardDocFlows"></i> Ajouter au panier
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btnCloseModalDetailFormalite" onclick="hideModalDetailFormalite()">Fermer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Navbat HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top scrolling-navbar">
<div class="container">
    <div class="theme-header clearfix">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-navbar" aria-controls="main-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                <span class="lni-menu"></span>
                <span class="lni-menu"></span>
                <span class="lni-menu"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto w-100 justify-content-end" id="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                        Accueil
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="apropos.html">
                        A Propos
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="inscription.html">S'inscrire</a>
                </li>
                <li class="button-group">
                    <a href="login.html" class="button btn btn-common"><i class="lni-user"></i> Se connecter</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mobile-menu" data-logo="assets/img/logo.png"></div>
```

[Here is what the view looks like when I call my modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzcUQ.png)

Comment: Are you use Master Page or _Layout Page in this case?

Comment: @HassanHosseini I use _Layout Page

Comment: this problem is not related to JS so you can remove your JS code and please add your navigation bar for better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is problem of `z-index` in `navigation bar`

add below CSS in your project, replace `navbar` class with your `main navigation bar class`

```
.modal-open .navbar {
    z-index: 1100;
}
```

Comment: I try to add that but I still have the same result, nothing's changed.

Comment: can you tell me the `z-index` of your navigation bar?

Comment: Here is the CSS of the NavBar: 1. is in bootstrap.css .fixed-top {z-index: 1030;} and 2. Found in main.css .top-nav-collapse {z-index: 999999;}.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just found the solution, which was to remove the z-index:999999 in my main.css file.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, which consisted in removing the z-index:999999 in my main.css file and leaving just the one in bootstrap.css z-index: 1030